# Breaking a video into predefined chunks

Tags: java, video, video-processing

I would like to know how to break a video into frames and store them a collection.  I have several cameras that collect at different frame rate and I would like to be able to input the video file as like a `.avi` or `.mp4` and have to work with a collection (probably LinkedList) of frames.  Somewhere in the code I would inject the framerate dependency which I can do on my own.  I just don't know how to cut up the video.  Someone suggested JMF but I am very confused by it.  Does anyone know of any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) is Java library on top of the ffmpeg libraries that makes a task like this relatively easy from Java. Look at the tutorials on the site for a quick start.